# Creating a csv dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I am trying to join some Time series CSV files on different stocks. I manage to get my data in separate CSV file and now I want to join them all together with Date as an Index and keep only their closing price. To identify which closing price corresponds to which ticker I have to rename the column "Close" to the name of the ticker that is contained in the filename. The files have all the following naming convention: "ticker.csv". This code is inspired from a website pythonprogramming.net and I tried to adapt if to my situation. (link here: https://pythonprogramming.net/sp500-company-price-data-python-programming-for-finance/)

I already looked up a lot of solution online but none answered my problems.

Why is my code telling me there is a keyerror when I try to set Date as an Index?

Also if I comment this line and try to drop some columns it tells that the labels do not exist whereas there are clearly indicated in the 1st row of each csv.
[AREX.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRuxL.png)

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
path = "C:/Users/xx/Desktop/Equity"
path1 = "C:/Users/xx/Desktop/Equity/Merged.csv"

def concatenate(indir=path, outfile = path1):
    os.chdir(indir)
    fileList = glob.glob("*.csv")
    ticker = []
    for filename in fileList:
        print(filename)
        df=pd.read_csv(filename, error_bad_lines=False)
        ticker.append(df)
        df.set_index("date", inplace=True)        
        df.rename(columns = {"close": ticker}, inplace = True)
        df.drop(["Open","High","Low","Volume","Open interest"],axis = 1, inplace=True)
        df=df.join(df, how="outer")

    print(df.head())
    df.to_csv('Merged.csv')

concatenate()
```

Could anyone help me with that ? 
Thank you very much anyway for anyhelp you can give me ! :)

Comment: what do you get when you do `df['date']`?

Comment: Hello, I just tried it again and i get Keyerror: 'date'

Comment: there's no date field on your df, that's why. Do `list(df)`

Comment: @Yuca it is suppose to output a list of different dataframes ? 
cause it only gives me filenames

Comment: it's supposed to give you the columns of your dataframe

Comment: ok so apparently the name of my columns are the name of each CSV file I want to merge :/ this makes no sense to me 

`fileList = glob.glob("*.csv")
    ticker = []
    for filename in fileList:
        print(filename)
        df=pd.read_csv(filename, error_bad_lines=False)
        ticker.append(df)
        list(df)`

Comment: just do a dummy test and run `df = pd.read_csv(filename)` pick a valid filename and see what you get in df

Comment: Ok if i do this with a single file it works and outputs the correct columns:
['Date;Close;Open;High;Low;Volume;Open interest']

Comment: what's the content of filelist?

Comment: From what i understood file list grabes all the CSV files in the directory. So it should be a list

Comment: yeah, can we confirm that fileList is in fact a list of files?

Comment: Ok I think the problem is whith the separator as it is a ";"..... si I should specify somewhere what it is

Comment: yes, you need to do read_csv(filename, sep = ';')

Comment: yes i have already corrected now i just need to correct this error 
"ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['Close'], dtype='object')" But I hope there will be some answer on how to fix that 

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I have come accross the answer and this is the finale code:

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import shutil
def concatenate(indir="C:/Users/xx/Desktop/Equity_Merton", outfile = "C:/Users/xx/Desktop/Equity_Merton/Merged.csv"):
    os.chdir(indir)    
    fileList = glob.glob("*.csv")
    ticker = []
    main_df = pd.DataFrame()
    for filename in fileList:
        print(filename)
        df=pd.read_csv(filename, sep = ";")
        ticker.append(df)
        df.set_index("Date", inplace=True)        
        df.rename(columns = {"Close": filename[0:len(filename) - 4]}, inplace = True)
#        print(df[filename])
        df.drop(["Open","High","Low","Volume","Open interest"],axis = 1, inplace=True)

        if main_df.empty:
            main_df = df
        else:
            main_df = main_df.join(df, how='outer')

    print(main_df.tail())
    main_df.to_csv('Merton_Merged.csv')         
    shutil.move("Merton_Merged.csv", "../Merton_Merged.csv")
```

Thank you @yuca for your help !
The last problem was a simple indetation problem...